# Apollo React Client: How to detect if cache is updated for a specific Type or query?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a function that should be called every time whenever a specific type or query is updated from the cache.

I could not find any solution online yet. Is it really possible?

I would highly appreciate any response.

Thanks

Comment: What do You mean by "specific type of query"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `refetchQueries` e.g:

```
const [mutate, { data, error }] = useQuery(
  ADD_TODO,
  {
    refetchQueries: [
      { query: GET_ALL_TODOS }
    ]
  }
)
```

In this case I used `mutation` but you can use with `useQuery`, no problems.

ref: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/caching/when-to-use-refetch-queries/